# Identificando palavras que começam com maiúsculas em listas

Tags: python-3.x

Eu queria identificar se o item da lista tem a primeira letra maiúscula.
Já tentei usar o For e o While, mas o resultado é sempre o mesmo.

```
texto = input('Texto: ')
texto.split()
cont = 0
for c in texto:
    if cont != 0:
        a = c[0]
        if a.isupper:
            assunto = True
            a = c
            break
    cont += 1
if assunto:
    print(a)
else:
    print('Sem assunto')
```

A resposta do código sempre é a segunda letra da primeira palavra, e eu não sei o motivo.

**Exemplo:** Se a frase é "Você curte Sushi?", o programa vai retornar a letra "O", que está na palavra "Você". Estranhamente, ela só retorna as letras que estão nesse lugar.

O que há de errado com o código?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes

A variável `texto` pegará uma entrada.

```
texto = input('Texto: ')
```

Esta parte divide o texto em palavras usando o espaço como delimitador, **porém** teria que atribuir o resultado a uma variável

```
texto.split()
```

```
frase = texto.split()
```

Agora, basta iterar e checar a primeira letra de cada palavra

```
for palavra in frase:
   if palavra[0].isupper():
      # faça o que quiser
```

**Nota** `isupper()` é um método e deve ser chamado como tal

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, meu problema foi resolvido e isso me será bastante útil

Comment: Eu descobri o problema. O isupper() retorna True pra espaços